# What is the most performant method for splitting strings?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, split

**Code**

```
create table ExampleTable
(
    Name varchar(500)
    CultureCode(5)
)

insert into ExampleTable values('Dit is een test', 'nl-NL')
insert into ExampleTable values('This is a test', 'en-GB')
insert into ExampleTable values('Ceci est un test', 'fr-FR')
insert into ExampleTable values('Dies ist ein Test', 'de-DE')

create procedure GetNameByCultures
(
@CultureCodes varchar(250)
)
as 
begin
//Get ExampleTable items according to the culture codes stated in @CultureCodes
end
```

-Example:

```
CREATE TYPE StringListType AS TABLE
(
    [str] varchar(5) NULL
)
```

I am using MS SQL 2012 V11.0.2100.60

**Situation**

I'm trying to find the best way (Performance wise) to extract the labels. 
Methods I have thought of, but not yet tested are:

- Creating a user defined table type as shown in the above.

Upside: I know it has almost no performance on the database.

Downside: I have to add another parameter to the stored procedure.

- Creating a function which splits a string by the char: ','

Downside: I know using "Right", "Left", "Like" and other varchar converting / editing properties are slow in SQL

UpSide: I can keep the processing in the database.

In the current situation i'm only sending one culturecode inside a user defined table type. 
So it's impossible to add the culturecode in this UDTT as you can't add a UDTT to a UDTT. 
My only option would be to add another parameter to the stored procedure which shouldn't be to much of a issue... but we like to keep it to only one.

Does anyone happen to know another (better?) method or should I go with one of these?

Comment: Which flavour of database?  I presume by [sql] you mean MS SQL Server.  If so, please say so.  And include the version number.  Both performance and the range of available techniques is likel to vary depending on which version you're using.

Comment: Using MS SQL 2012  V11.0.2100.60

Comment: Table valued parameter is the best way as you're using 2008 onwards. Read [these very thorough articles](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) on the different methods available, with analysis and performance details.

Comment: @TheunArbeider I've posted the comment as an answer, as requested :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table valued parameters are the best way as you're using 2008 onwards. ([See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)).

I would thoroughly recommend you read SQL Server MVP Erland Sommarskog's very comprehensive articles on the different methods available, with analysis and performance details.

- Article dedicated to [Table valued parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
- Article dedicated to [Some of the alternatives for SQL 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) (XML, string splitting, etc.)
- [General article page](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html), with links to the above, performance tests and SQL Server 2000 alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I would still pass the list of cultures as comma separated string, define a function which returns a table and then join this table to your example table. As long as the string contains a small number of elements, you will not notice any performance drop.

If you can live with the limitation of passing a maximum of N culture codes, you could try something like this

```
create procedure GetNameByCulture 
  @CultureInfo varchar(5),
  @CultureInfo1 varchar(5) = null,
  @CultureInfo2 varchar(5) = null
as
 select e.* 
   from ExampleTable e 
        join (
          select @CultureInfo as CultureInfo union
          select @CultureInfo1 union
          select @CultureInfo2
          ) x 
          on e.CultureInfo = x.CultureInfo
```

This would be a bit faster than the string version, I guess. But as I mentioned, it won't be a big deal anyway.

Comment: In the example I use only 4 translations.. but I could be that in the future we'll have 30 or 40 translations... will it still be no issue then?

Comment: If you use this method (i.e. having 30-40 optional parameters) no. Personally, I don't like this solution, it seems to be 'ugly' from an aesthetic point of view ('code prettyness'). But that is only my personal opinion. But if performance is your issue, why don't you just implement the three methods (string vs. table vs. optional parameters) and do some testing?

Answer (score 0):

what about using replace and cast for xml instead left/right to split string?

```
    declare @ExampleTable table
    (
        Name varchar(500),
        CultureCode varchar(5)
    )

    insert into @ExampleTable values('Dit is een test', 'nl-NL')
    insert into @ExampleTable values('This is a test', 'en-GB')
    insert into @ExampleTable values('Ceci est un test', 'fr-FR')
    insert into @ExampleTable values('Dies ist ein Test', 'de-DE')


    declare @CultureCodes varchar(250)
    set @CultureCodes = 'nl-NL,en-GB,fr-FR'

    declare @xml xml
    set @xml = cast('<culturecodes><culture>'+REPLACE(@CultureCodes,',','</culture><culture>')+'</culture></culturecodes>' as xml)

    select 
           C.element.value('.','varchar(max)') as CultureCode_splited
          ,E.CultureCode 
          ,E.name
    from @xml.nodes('/culturecodes/culture')C(element)
    inner join @ExampleTable E
    on E.CultureCode = C.element.value('.','varchar(max)')
```

resultset seems like this...

```
    CultureCode_splited     CultureCode name
    nl-NL                   nl-NL       Dit is een test
    en-GB                   en-GB       This is a test
    fr-FR                   fr-FR       Ceci est un test
```

Comment: I am uncertain about replace.. but I've been told and have experience that any string altering methods in SQL comes at a cost of perfomance, and performance is our main priority here!